# NSOpenPanel alternative for c++

Tags: core-foundation, nsopenpanel

I am trying to locate an alternative to NSOpenPanel that I can use from a purely c++ class methods. I know that windows provides a lot of options for this, but I need this for a mac system. I have been searching for something in the core-foundation stuff, but I havent been able to find anything meaningful. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Core foundation framework does not contain any such APIs. Its actually framework that provides many model classes. Earlier those who don't want to use Cocoa framework were using Carbon framework. 
Earlier Open panel was done using Navigation services. For various methods you can look at header file `NavigationServices/Navigation.h`. Navigation services is not available for Mac OS X 64 bit application.